# How to generate CSS with loop in less

Tags: css, less

I am not familiar with `Less`. In my understanding, I think `Less` can transform the `less` format file to standard `css` file(if I am wrong, please correct me). Now I have a question below.

Say you would generate 100 CSS classes like below(from `.span1` to `.span100`) in a single CSS file. I want to know whether `less` can generate a CSS file like it?

```
...
.span5 {
  width: 5%;
}

.span4 {
  width: 4%;
}

.span3 {
  width: 3%;
}

.span2 {
  width: 2%;
}

.span1 {
  width: 1%;
}
```

Comment: This is a perfectly legitimate question and is exactly the one I had. Please re-open this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

All, I found a way to output css in loop. pleae review it .thanks.

```
@iterations: 100;

// helper class, will never show up in resulting css
// will be called as long the index is above 0
.loopingClass (@index) when (@index > 0) {

    // create the actual css selector, example will result in
    // .myclass_30, .myclass_28, .... , .myclass_1
    (~".span@{index}") {
        // your resulting css
        width: percentage((@index - 1) *0.01);
    }

    // next iteration
    .loopingClass(@index - 1);
}

// end the loop when index is 0
.loopingClass (0) {}

// "call" the loopingClass the first time with highest value
.loopingClass (@iterations);
```

Comment: Please refer to the Less source code of Bootstrap (namely mixins.less). Search for ".spanX" string, I hope that it's next to what you mean to get at.

Comment: You use [guard](http://leafo.net/lessphp/docs/#guards) along with a recursive [mixin](http://leafo.net/lessphp/docs/#mixins) as did the authors of Bootstrap.

Comment: Please head to this post: [Do a loop with LESS css](http://blog.thehippo.de/2012/04/programming/do-a-loop-with-less-css/).

Comment: @Joe.wang code was not working in less2css.org. So, I played and got this:`

@iterations: 100;


.loopingClass (@index) when (@index > 0) {

    .span@{index} {
        
        width: percentage((@index ) *0.01);
    }


    .loopingClass(@index - 5);
}


.loopingClass (0) {}


.loopingClass (@iterations);`


@iterations: 100;


.loopingClass (@index) when (@index > 0) {

    .span@{index} {
        
        width: percentage((@index ) *0.01);
    }


    .loopingClass(@index - 5);
}


.loopingClass (0) {}


.loopingClass (@iterations);
`

Answer (score 67):

#### Update, 3/28/2022:

***Requires Less v3.9.0***

```
each(range(1%, 100%, 1), {
  .span-@{index} {
    width: @value;
  }
});
```

**Output**

```css
.span-1 {
  width: 1%;
}
.span-2 {
  width: 2%;
}
.span-3 {
  width: 3%;
}
.
.
.
.span-98 {
  width: 98%;
}
.span-99 {
  width: 99%;
}
.span-100 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Quoting the [docs](https://lesscss.org/functions):

> Creating a `for` loop using `range` and `each`
>
> *Requires Less v3.9.0*
>
> You can emulate a `for` loop simply by generating a numerical list and
> using `each` to expand it to a ruleset.

**Notes:**

- `range(1%, 100%, 1)`: makes a list starting from 1% to 100%, with step value of 1, that is:

  `1% 2% 3% ... 100%`
- `each(list, rules)`: Bind the evaluation of a ruleset to each member of a list.

  - `@value`: each value in the list, i.e. `1%`, `2%`, ...
  - `@index`: index of each value, starting from 1 (numerical position, 1-based)

#### Original Answer:

Try this:

```
@iterations: 5;
.span-loop (@i) when (@i > 0) {
    .span-@{i} {
        width: ~"@{i}%";
    }
    .span-loop(@i - 1);
}
.span-loop (@iterations);
```

**Output:**

```
.span-5 {
  width: 5%;
}
.span-4 {
  width: 4%;
}
.span-3 {
  width: 3%;
}
.span-2 {
  width: 2%;
}
.span-1 {
  width: 1%;
}
```

You can try it out on [less2css](https://lesscss.org/less-preview/).

#### Update, 4/3/2014

**Here is a more flexible version with more options:**

```
.custom-loop( @base-value:@n ; @n ; @unit : px; @j : 1 ;@_s:0 ; @step-size:1  ; @selector:~".span-"; @property : width)
when not(@n=0)  {
  
  @size : @base-value+@_s;
  @{selector}@{j}{
    @{property} : ~"@{size}@{unit}";
  }
  .custom-loop(@base-value ,  (@n - 1), @unit , (@j + 1) ,  (@_s+@step-size) , @step-size,  @selector, @property);
}
```

You can call this by only `@n` which is the required argument:

```
.custom-loop(@n:3);
```

Which will output:

```
.span-1 {
  width: 3px;
}
.span-2 {
  width: 4px;
}
.span-3 {
  width: 5px;
}
```

But if you want to have control over each parameter, here is an example using all custom parameters:

```
.custom-loop( @n: 3 , @base-value:1, @unit: '%', @property:font-size, @selector: ~".fs-", @step-size: 2);
```

This will output:

```
.fs-1 {
  font-size: 1%;
}
.fs-2 {
  font-size: 3%;
}
.fs-3 {
  font-size: 5%;
}
```

### Parameter descriptions

1. **@n** : *integer*, The number of iterations.
2. **@base-value** (optional): *integer*,  The starting value for the loop to be assigned to the property. Default value is the same is the value assigned for the number of iterations `@n`.
3. **@unit** (optional): *string*, The unit for the property. Default value is `px`.
4. **@property** (optional): *non-string* or *string* The CSS property. Default value is `width`
5. **@selector** (optional): *escaped string*, The selector used for the loop. Could be anything as long as it is passed in as a escaped string.
6. **@step-size** (optional): *integer*, The value by which the loop increments by.

### NOTES

**Note 1:** The custom selector is passed in as a escaped string. If it is not escaped, it is not going to work as expected.

**Note 2:** The mixin is called by explicitly using the parameter name. This has some advantages and disadvantages:

**Note 3:** The unit is passed in as a string.

**Advantages**

1. It is clear what parameter is called
2. You don't have to rely on the order of parameters and remember which parameter comes first, second, …

**Disadvantages**

1. I guess it looks a bit ugly ?
2. (add to the list and/or change the implementation if you know a better one)

Comment: Only this syntax works with less.php (leafo), thanks !

Comment: One small critique. I prefer `@j:@base-value` and `(@j+@step-size)` so that I get meaningful class names instead of an index without context. In your solution, the class name is not matching the value that's set in the property when base-value != step-size != 1.

Comment: you are god bro

Answer (score 13):

Please note, that since version 3.7 Less has an [each()](http://lesscss.org/functions/#list-functions-each) function, which can be easily used with the `range()` function to produce the wanted code - like this:

```
each(range(100),{
    .span@{value} { width: @value * 1%; }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to do within given methods.

[image]

But possible like this:

```
.loopingClass (@index) when (@index > 0){
  .span_@{index}{
    width: @index px;
  }
  .loopingClass(@index - 1);
}
.loopingClass(5);
```

Resilt will be like this:

```
.span_100 {
  width: 100 px;
}
.span_99 {
  width: 99 px;
}
.span_98 {
  width: 98 px;
}
.span_97 {
  width: 97 px;
}
.span_96 {
  width: 96 px;
}
.span_95 {
  width: 95 px;
}

and e.t.c.
```

Comment: Please add answer with code or fiddle. picture on code is consider bad   answer

Comment: Isn't this answer a duplicate of @Amin answer?