# Generate Classes Using Loop in Less

Tags: css, sass, less

I'm trying to generate margin classes in Less. I've the code:

```
.generate-margin(5);

.generate-margin(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< @n) {

  .mb-@{i} {

    margin-bottom: (@i * 5px) !important;
  }
  .generate-margin(@n, (@i + 1));
}
```

Which Outputs:

```
.mb-1 {
  margin-bottom: 5px !important;
}
.mb-2 {
  margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}
.mb-3 {
  margin-bottom: 15px !important;
}
.mb-4 {
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
}
.mb-5 {
  margin-bottom: 25px !important;
}
```

But instead of **.mb-1, .mb-2, .mb-3, .mb-4, .mb-5** I want **.mb-5, .mb-10, .mb-15, .mb-20, .mb-25**. How to do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate CSS with loop in less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15239785/how-to-generate-css-with-loop-in-less)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a variable to store the size of the current margin:

```
.generate-margin(5);

.generate-margin(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< @n) {

  @marginSize: @i*5;

  .mb-@{marginSize} {

    margin-bottom: (@i * 5px) !important;
  }
  .generate-margin(@n, (@i + 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Logic I think its:

```
.generate-margin(5);

.generate-margin(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< @n) {
     .mb-@{i * 5} {
         margin-bottom: (@i * 5px) !important;
     }
    .generate-margin(@n, (@i + 1));
}
```